# Linphone iOS behind CGNAT sets wrong Contact Header

Tags: nat, voip, ios, sip

We are using Linphone client on iOS over Verizon network. Our client sends wrong IP address on Contact header at 200 OK message as a response to INVITE message from Asterisk.

[SIP trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ognU0.png)

Our client's correct public IP address is 70.214.115.17 as it appears on IPv4 source. We spotted the problem on the fact that on Contact Header we ask from Asterisk to respond to us at IP address 100.93.81.213.

Since this IP address is unreachable, our client never receives an ACK response from Asterisk. As a result, our call (in a continuous failure to receive ACK message) is terminated on 32 seconds exactly.

According to IANA, this IP address is used for CGNAT purposes.

This problem doesn't appear every time but it appears randomly.

We would appreciate any of your assistance.